# Why does adjust box not resize to the dimensions given

Tags: boxes, paragraphs, adjustbox

Hi looking to understand this a little better. Why does `adjustbox` not resize the text in the following example so that it fits the dimensions I think I'm specifying. e.g a 4in x 4in box. Am I doing something wrong and how do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{frame,max height=4in,max width=4in}
\parbox{4in}{
\lipsum[1-3]}    
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As @IanThompson mentioned, you're specifying `max height`, which is different from `max totalheight`, since your `\parbox` has depth (included in `totalheight` but not in `height`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boxes in `TeX` have both height and depth. We can enquire about the dimensions of the box in question as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\Abox
\savebox\Abox{\parbox{4in}{\lipsum[1-3]}}
\newlength\mydp
\newlength\myhg
\settodepth\mydp{\usebox{\Abox}}
\settoheight\myhg{\usebox{\Abox}}
\showthe\mydp
\showthe\myhg
\end{document}
```

In this way, we obtain a height of `204.97221pt` and a depth of `209.97223pt`. Since `1in=72.27pt`, this means that the height and depth of the box are approximately `2.84in` and `2.91in`, respectively. Consequently, setting `max height=4in` has no effect. According to page 5 of the [adjustbox package manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox), `totalheight` is `height` plus `depth`, so if you want the actual height of the box on the page to be restricted to `4in` you should use `totalheight` in place of `height`. To make the width of the box remain the same (so the aspect ratio of the box changes), you need to set `width` and `totalheight`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{width=4in,totalheight=4in}{\parbox{4in}{\lipsum[1-3]}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\mydp}{\dp\Abox}` is much more efficient (although not officially documented in LaTeX).

Comment: Hi @Ian. Tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Rather than a 4x4 box with text inside I get a longish rectangle. its 4" long but quite a lot narrower.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha --- What you want is not clear from the question; maybe you could edit it to clarify. In my answer, the box is scaled so that it fits within your settings for maximum width and height, while keeping the aspect ratio. If you want a `4in` by `4in` box you can use `scale` (see section 4.4 of the package manual).

Comment: Thanks @Ian I've adjusted my question. My understanding of the scale key-value was that it was limited to an <h-factor> and <v-factor>, I'm not sure how I'd use it to specify a fixed size box.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha --- I have edited my answer.